# Pycharm configuration difference between running and debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a folder structure where

```
project_name
└───folder_level_1
│   └───folder_level_2
│   │   └───folder_level_3
│   │       └─── folder_level_4
│   │       │    └─── ...
|   |       |    main.py
```

I have marked folder_level_1/2/3 as source roots in Pycharm.

When I try to run main.py in debug - it works, but if I run normally I get an error that
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named folder_level_1.folder_level_2.folder_level_3. In each level I have an **init**.py as well.

Running it with pipenv environment if that helps.

How should I solve that?

Comment: Why have you marked all of them as source roots? If each directories contains an init file, that none of them are source roots, only `project_name` is.

Comment: I was trying different configurations - I tried just putting project_name as source root and I encounter the same problem.